# Is the visit frequency of a disjoint union the series of the visit frequencies?

Tags: ergodic-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu, f)$ be an invariant system, $\mu$ be a probability, $\mathcal{B} 
\subset \mathcal{A}$ be a countable algebra generating $\mathcal{A}$ and $(A_k)_{k \ge 0}$ be a pairwise disjoint sequence of elements in $\mathcal{B}$.
Suppose $x \in X$ is such that $\lim_n \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \mathcal{X}_{A_k} \circ f^j (x) = l_k \in [0,1], \forall k \ge 0$.

How do we show (if true) that  $$\lim_n \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \mathcal{X}_{A} \circ f^j (x) =\lim_n \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \mathcal{X}_{A_k} \circ f^j (x)$$ equals $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \lim_n \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \mathcal{X}_{A_k} \circ f^j (x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty l_k \in \mathbb{R} \text{ ?}$$ (i.e., that the visit frequency of a disjoint union is the series of the visit frequencies)

In order to switch limit and series, I've tried to write the series on $k$ as an integral against the counting measure to use monotone convergence theorem, dominated convergence theorem and uniform convergence with no success (I've also tried to take monotone subsequences working for all $k$'s). Fatou´s lemma also gives us a partial inequality with liminf, but I was not able to come up with the remaining inequality for the limsup. I was also not able to find arguments using a negation and 'an epsilon of room'.

This question sounds so natural that I got confused. Maybe I´m not considering enough information from the dynamical systems context. Is there a better indirect approach to get the result?

Thanks!
Lucas Amorim.

Comment: Have you tried to check whether towers can perhaps be used to construct a counterexample? It is clearly a matter of large deviations.

Comment: John, I was expecting a positive answer for the question, since it is a hidden passage in a proof of the ergodic decomposition theorem ([see](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=vlRyCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA148&dq=marcelo+viana+ergodic+theory+ergodic+decomposition+monotone+class&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjphODd0_3aAhUCjpAKHTG-BHkQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=marcelo%20viana%20ergodic%20theory%20ergodic%20decomposition%20monotone%20class)). I have no knowledge of large deviations, but I will try to find a counterexample using towers. It will indicate I extracted the "subquestion" from the proof missing something.

Comment: Understood, but there you have more information: namely, in your question $x$ is fixed (as least it is formulated seeming to suggest that). The important information is what are the elements of the measurable partition. Just a note: "soujourn"??? everybody uses "return". On your question, I bet that there are counterexamples.

Comment: Please let me know if using the information on the fibers you are able to complete the proof.

Comment: The point $x$ is fixed in my question. Yes, the context is richer there. I will work on this tonight and also consider if the partition info is what is missing to reach the desired conclusion. I will update you soon. Thanks. (Soujourn was probably a typo)

Comment: Yes, there is a counterexample for the question. Consider a countable orbit, non periodic, starting at x (eg., a transalation on $\mathbb{N}$). Consider $A_k=\{f^k(x)\}$. The visit frequency of x for each $A_k$ is 0 (otherwise it would be periodic), but the visit frequency of the union is 1. I'm still not done with that passage of the book, but I'm betting closer. Probably I'm still missing some detail. I will update here  and turn all conclusions in an answer soon.

Comment: John, I was discussing with some colleagues and I seems that this counterexample can still be adapted to say that passage/argument of the proof doesn't proceed. I will email the author this week to see what he has to say.